# How to draw a cartogram in r without zip code, longitude and latitude?

Tags: r, geospatial, latitude-longitude, date-conversion, cartogram

I want to make a cartogram with data from my country Suriname. This diagram should show the location on the map together with the number of the schools. The only data I have is:

| District | Ressort | Coordinaten | Schoolcode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Paramaribo | Beekhuizen | 5°30'29,88"NB, 55°10'44,04"WL | A1 |
| Paramaribo | Beekhuizen | 5°30'29,88"NB, 55°10'44,04"WL | A2 |
| Paramaribo | Centrum | 5°30'29,9"NB, 55°10'44,0"WL | A3 |
| Paramaribo | Beekhuizen | 5°30'29,88"NB, 55°10'44,04"WL | A4 |
| Paramaribo | Welgelegen | 5°50'33"NB, 55°13'7"WL | A5 |
| Wanica | Nieuwe Grond | 5°45'NB, 55°13'WL | A6 |
| Wanica | Domburg | 5°42'NB, 55°5'WL | A7 |
| Wanica | Domburg | 5°42'NB, 55°5'WL | A8 |

I checked for instruction video and found instructions about constructing a cartogram with zip codes and with the longitude and latitude.
Is it possible to use this data in r to construct a cartogram?
If yes, can you give me some instruction how to do that?
If the answer is no, is it possible to convert this column into the longitude and latitude or even zipcode of data? If yes, how can I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For simple map plots I had great success using `ggplot2::geom_sf`. Maybe you don't even need to convert the polar coordinates to longitude/latitude, but even if this should be quite straight forward...

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that should get you started; additional comments are inline.

#### Load necessary libraries

```r
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(sf)
```

#### Download Suriname shape files

```r
# Download Suriname shape files of country, district and resort boundaries
# Source: https://data.humdata.org/dataset/suriname-administrative-level-0-1-and-2-boundaries
url <- "https://data.humdata.org/dataset/ab35e673-76f2-43e5-a6a4-a5b81f9e093c/resource/fd31ebfd-bf77-4b7d-902f-3ea3a9c2d7a2/download/sur_adm_2017_shp.zip"
download.file(url, "suriname_data.zip")
unzip("suriname_data.zip", exdir = "data")
```

Data are stored in folder ./data. The ZIP file also contains a PDF with metadata information. I suggest taking a look.

#### Read Suriname district shapefile

```r
# Read shapefile of Suriname districts
# Note: Geodetic CRS = WGS84
suriname_district <- st_read("data/sur_admbnda_adm1_2017.shp")
```

#### Parse local data

```r
# Define custom function to parse coordinates from your data.frame
parse_coordinaten <- function(x) {

    x %>%
    str_remove_all("(NB|WL)") %>%        # Remove NB and WL suffixes
    str_split(", ") %>%                  # Split into lat/long string
    map(~ .x %>%
        str_replace_all(",", ".") %>%    # Replace , with . decimal separator
        str_split("[^(\\d|\\.)]") %>%    # Split each lat/long on non-digit char
        map_dbl(function(w) w %>%        # Convert deg/min/sec to fractional degree
            as.numeric() %>%
            multiply_by(c(1, 1/60, 1/3600)) %>%
            sum(na.rm = TRUE)
        ) %>%
        multiply_by(c(1, -1)) %>%        # Multiply long by -1 since west of prime meridian 
        setNames(c("lat", "lon")) %>%   
        bind_rows()
    ) %>%
        bind_rows()
}

# Read data; I assume you have a `data.frame` named `df` 
# Note: `dput(df)` included in the appendix
data <- df %>%
    mutate(Coordinaten = map(Coordinaten, parse_coordinaten)) %>%
    unnest(Coordinaten) %>%
    st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
    mutate(label = paste(District, Ressort, Schoolcode, sep = "<br>"))
```

#### Plot

```r
# Plot using `leaflet`
library(leaflet)
pal <- colorFactor("Spectral", levels = suriname_district$ADM1_NL)
leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>% 
    addPolygons(
        fillColor = ~pal(ADM1_NL),
        fillOpacity = 0.6,
        weight = 0,
        data = suriname_district) %>%
    addMarkers(
        data = data,
        label = ~map(label, htmltools::HTML))
```

[image]

`leaflet` allows for a lot of customisation; for example, you can tweak the marker labels, add resort boundaries, etc.

---

#### Appendix: Sample data

```r
df <- structure(list(District = c("Paramaribo", "Paramaribo", "Paramaribo", 
"Paramaribo", "Paramaribo", "Wanica", "Wanica", "Wanica"), Ressort = c("Beekhuizen", 
"Beekhuizen", "Centrum", "Beekhuizen", "Welgelegen", "Nieuwe Grond", 
"Domburg", "Domburg"), Coordinaten = c("5°30'29,88NB, 55°10'44,04WL", 
"5°30'29,88NB, 55°10'44,04WL", "5°30'29,9NB, 55°10'44,0WL", 
"5°30'29,88NB, 55°10'44,04WL", "5°50'33NB, 55°13'7WL", "5°45'NB, 55°13'WL", 
"5°42'NB, 55°5'WL", "5°42'NB, 55°5'WL"), Schoolcode = c("A1", 
"A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The code did gave me some errors in the R version 4.0.5 , but it runs fine in R studio. The code is explained neatly, but it will take a while before I will be able to implement it in other situations. Bot thanks a lot.